# Trapezoid shape with angled top and right side

Tags: css, css-shapes

It is a curved div basically:

[image: curved div]

So it is possible to do with just CSS and no images?

Comment: I don;t think it is... those in that article are all symmetrical shapes and this is not.  Those ones use the border hack to get their angles.

Comment: "css or css3" Um, they're the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Well... I was the biggest skeptic of this shape, but it seems it is possible O_o

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sGJtF/)

#### HTML

```
<div class="shape one"></div>
<div class="shape two"></div>
<div class="shape three"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.shape
{
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

.one
{
    border-width:0px;
    border-bottom:10px solid red;
    border-left:200px solid #fff;
    width:0px;
}

.two
{
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    clear:left;
}

.three
{
    border-width:0px;
    border-top:50px solid red;
    border-right:10px solid #fff;
    width:0px;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `border` method looks grainy in the browsers I tested. Here's a method using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements and CSS `transform: skew()` that looks smoother. You can adjust the angles as needed. This uses only one `<div>`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### HTML:

```html
<div class="quadrilateral"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
.quadrilateral {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}
.quadrilateral::before {
    background-color: red;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 61px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    top: -11px;
    transform:             skewX( -5deg ); 
        -ms-transform:     skewX( -5deg ); 
        -webkit-transform: skewX( -5deg ); 
        -o-transform:      skewX( -5deg ); 
        -moz-transform:    skewX( -5deg ); 
    width: 10px;
}
.quadrilateral::after {
    background-color: red;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    transform:             skewY( -2deg ); 
        -ms-transform:     skewY( -2deg ); 
        -webkit-transform: skewY( -2deg ); 
        -o-transform:      skewY( -2deg ); 
        -moz-transform:    skewY( -2deg ); 
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of CSS, consider using SVG. It's supported in all major browsers and that shape would be very very small in SVG format. It also would be in your DOM tree so you could bind events on it.